# vscode not compiling typescript file

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I found vscode failed to compile my typescript code even I followed exactly their tutorial:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-compiling

After all the configurations of the above tutorial, when I click "Run -> Run without Debugging", I got:

> Cannot launch program '/Users/username/Desktop/work/ts/main.ts'
>   because corresponding JavaScript cannot be found.

However, if I run

> tsc

on terminal, then "Run -> Run without Debugging" works.

"main.ts":

```
  let a : Array<number> = [1,2,3]
  let b : number[] = a
  console.log(a === b)
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es5",
      "module": "esnext",
      "outDir": "out",
      "sourceMap": true,
    }
}
```

launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/main.ts",
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**/*.js"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

tasks.json:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "typescript",
            "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$tsc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "label": "tsc: build - tsconfig.json"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `tasks.json` need to change label, in example `"label": "build"`

In `launch.json` we can use preLaunchTask property - `"preLaunchTask": "build"`

Run with debug or without it should start build and stay watching. Build task itself should also work by `Ctrl+Shift+B`

launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/main.ts",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/out/**/*.js"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

tasks.json

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "type": "typescript",
            "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$tsc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

also you may want to exclude some directories

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "esnext",
    "outDir": "out",
    "sourceMap": true,
  },
  "exclude": ["**/node_modules/*", "out", "coverage"]
}
```